# Prove: for every $4k$ white & black balls $2k$ white & $2k$ black,placed in arbitrary order,there are $2k$ consecutive balls, $k$ white,$k$ black.

Tags: combinatorics

The **problem** is: Prove that for every  $4k$ white and black balls where $2k$ of them are white and the other $2k$ black which are placed in a row with any arbitrary order, one can find  $2k$ consecutive balls such that $k$ of them are white and the other $k$, black.

Now I want to prove this with mathematical induction.

*Base Case:* $k=1\Rightarrow 4k=4$. Here $p(4k)$ is true for $k=1$, where $p(4k)$ indicates that there exists a consecutive collection of $2k$ balls such that $k$ of them are white and the other $k$ black. Reason: we've got 6 possible arrangement with 4 balls: BBWW, BWBW, BWWB, WBBW, WBWB, WWBB and with each scenario we can find at elast 2 consecutive balls 1 of which will be black and the other one white.

*Inductive Step:* Let's say $p$ is correct for $4k$ balls. Thus, there are $2k$ consecutive balls, $k$ of which are black and the other $k$ white. I need to prove that $p$ is also true for $4k+4$ balls. **Now the question is:** Why should we have $2k+2$ consecutive balls, $k+1$ black and $k+1$ white, after adding the new 4 balls (2 white and 2 black) ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think I would use induction for that.

Instead, let an arrangement of $4k$ balls be given, and let
$$ f(n) = \text{the number of white balls in positions }n\text{ through }n+2k-1 $$
for $1\le n\le 2k+1$.

Then $f(1)+f(2k+1)=2k$ because that is the number of white balls in total.

Now if $f(1)=f(2k+1)=k$, then we're done. Otherwise either $f(1)<k<f(2k+1)$ or $f(1)>k>f(2k+1)$. But the value of $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$ cannot differ by more than $1$, so somewhere between $1$ and $2k+1$ there must be an $n$ with $f(n)=k$, Q.E.D.

Comment: Great approach. But, I didn't understand this part of your solution: *so somewhere between 1 and $2k+1$ there must be an $n$ with $f(n)=k$*. I get this that we're moving one by one from (let's say) left. The number of white balls will be added or reduced one by one, but how do you know it will reach $k$ somewhere?

Comment: @Mill: The crucial fact is that $f(1)$ and $f(2k+1)$ are on _different_ sides of $k$ -- the only way to get from one to the other in steps of $1$ is to pass _through_ $k$.

Comment: @Mill If e.g. $n_0=1,n_1,n_2,\dots,n_m,n_{m+1}=5$ is some row of integers with $|n_i-n_{i+1}|\leq1$ then $2,3,4\in\{n_1,n_2,\dots,n_m\}$. This is small enough to try it out and get understanding of it.